# Improve join and fuzzymtch performance in PySpark or Delta Table using Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working with 7 different Dataframes where 3 come from CSVs stored in container/blob storages and the other 4 from a queries in sqldw. These dataframes comes from different sources but have same structure

[image]

I perform join after join and eliminate null values, adding a column to register which source it came from. It's all fairly simple, but for my last one I perform a join by the State and then a fuzzy match with the name.

[image]

**My dataframe has about 500k rows, but after this join it goes up to 30 Million and it takes over 30min to execute the join and fuzzymatches.**

I read about Delta Tables and how it can process petabytes really fast. I haven't really understood how it works. I have tried creating delta files and delta table from tutorials but when i ran the code it took over an hour just to create the delta table.

**Can anyone help me optimize this? Either using parquet or delta table, not sure what's the best way.**

My notebook connections are configured as follows:

```
### STORAGE ACCOUNT ###
storage_account_name = "[storageAccount]"
container_name = "[containerName]"
storage_account_access_key = "[key1]"
temp_blob_name = "[blobPath]"

storage_account_account_key = "fs.azure.account.key.{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(storage_account_name)
inputSource = "wasbs://{}@{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(container_name, storage_account_name)

spark.conf.set(
    storage_account_account_key,
    storage_account_access_key)

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
    storage_account_account_key,
    storage_account_account_key)

### DW DATABASE ###
dwDatabase = "[database]"
dwServer = "[server]"
dwJdbcPort = "[port]"

dwUser = "[user]"
dwPass = "[password]"

dwJdbcExtraOptions = "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
sqlDwUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ":" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass + ";$dwJdbcExtraOptions"
sqlDwUrlSmall = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ":" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass

spark.conf.set(
    "spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat",
    "true")
```

And to read my DataFrames:

```
### CSVs ###
df_csv = spark.read \
    .format('csv') \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", ";") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load(inputSource + "/sftp_files/{}/{}".format(dateFolder, fileName))

### SQL ###
df_sql = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
    .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall) \
    .option("tempDir", inputSource + temp_blob_name) \
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
    .option("query", queryText) \
    .load()
```

After fuzzy match I have this:

```
df = df\
    .orderBy(['Name','State','bestScore'], ascending=[True,True,False], na_position='last')\
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
threshold = 85
df = df.filter('bestScore &gt;= {}'.format(threshold))
```

Comment: Why are you joining, if the schema is the same on each file sounds like you just need to union these files? What is your final objective anywaysl? Seems like something that union and grouping could accomplish

Comment: Each dataframes comes from different sources. Each join I bring different information from each source. I use this structure to make joins and fuzzymatch (fuzzy when I don't have a direct join)

Comment: My fuzzymatch step is the most time consuming because I join my clients by the state key. So for each client I join with all clients in the save state. Aftwards I execute a fuzzy match on their name to see which is the correct client to bring the information from that source